# Using AuthenticatorActivity as application signin

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, android-authenticator

My app requires a sync adapter and therefore requires some authentication to take place before an account can be added to the `Accounts & Sync`.

I have followed the sample sync adapter app and have my app setup. I can for instance now verify a user on my server and have an account added to the `Accounts & Sync` section.

The thing is I would prefer this precedure of adding an account via the `AuthenticatorActivity` to take place inside my app for a better user experience.

So far I have added the `AuthenticatorActivity` when my app launches. As soon as authentication is successful it launches the `Accounts & Sync` settings section which completely ruins the applications signin/signup experience.

How can I stop this behaviour (launch of the `Accounts & Sync` setting on success) and allow my app to move to my next chosen step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is relatively simple procedure:

Make sure instead of using `startActivity` you use `startActivityForResult`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassYouAreLaunching.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0); // 0 reflects the requestCode seen in onActivityResult
```

Then you make sure you can capture the intent once it is sent back to you from the origin intent.

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED ) {

        finish();
    } else {
        // MAYBE        
        switch( requestCode ) {
            ...     

        }
    }
```

}